# AdMob pay per impression with Singleton

Tags: admob

I use an AdMob Banner Singleton in my Application. The Banner is loaded once at App lanuch and then I use one bannerView to show it in all Views.

In AdMob some Banners will be paid per 1k impressions. So I need to know how the SDK Count an impression.

Is an impression a shown Banner on a View or a Impression?

If I add the same Banner on different Views, will I get one Impression or multiple Impressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Admob then you are not getting paid per thousand impressions. You are getting paid per click. eCPM numbers are then calculated based upon the amount of click revenue you have generated per thousand impressions.

So to answer your question you will get multiple impressions but it will not increase your revenue. In fact it will probably lower your eCPM.

Comment: Okay, but my customers display also custom ads, there are the impressions important, because they sell impressions. So what is tecnically an impression?